# Swift2.2 iOS8以降向けアプリで起動時に処理するには

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

アプリ起動時に特定の処理をしたいのですが、

・完全にアプリが終了している状態からの起動
・アプリがバックグラウンドに存在する状態からの起動

上記の状態でそれぞれ別の処理をしたいのですが、それらを判別する方法はあるのでしょうか。
ご教授願います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
教えていただいた方法で処理を分けることができました！

Comment: 承認という機能がありますのでお使いください。

Answer (score 3):

その２つだけなら、

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

が呼ばれた場合は「完全にアプリが終了している状態からの起動」、

```
applicationWillEnterForeground:
```

が呼ばれた場合は「アプリがバックグラウンドに存在する状態からの起動」となるので、この２つのメソッドを使い分ければいいです。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3